# Is it possible to use file_data json object generated from SQL as input for Azure Search Document Extraction cognitive skill?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Is it possible to use the file_data input obtained from a SQL view to extract data using the Document Extraction Skill? In short what I would like to do is to is extract data from a document stored in a blob and add it to a searchable field in my index.

I have tried to return a JSON object as part of retrieving data from a SQL view.

```
       (
            select 
                top 1 
                'file' as [$type],
                '.....') as [url] 
            for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
        ) file_data
```

I have also tried adding an empty 'sasToken' property

The error that I receive is:

> Required skill input was not in the expected format.  Name: 'file_data', Source: '$(/document/file_data)', Error: 'Missing file reference object'

When I debug the skill the file_data is escaped json

file_data  "{ \"$type\":\"file\",\"url\":\"https:.....\" }"

If I copy the url and un escape the forward slashes \\/ I can open the document in a web browser.

If I try to evaluate the file_data expression (in the debugger) to try to extract the url part I do not get any results

[file_data expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cZOc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the input formats that can be accepted by the document extraction skill are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-document-extraction#skill-inputs

The data must be either BASE64-encoded binary content right in the JSON, like this:

```json
{
  "$type": "file",
  "data": "BASE64 encoded string of the file"
}
```

or refer to a blob, like this:

```json
{
  "$type": "file",
  "url": "URL to download file",
  "sasToken": "OPTIONAL: SAS token for authentication if the URL provided is for a file in blob storage"
}
```

So your JSON has the correct shape, that's not the issue (and there's no need to include an empty token). The issue is that the JSON is escaped, and I'm afraid that's inevitable if you try to build the object from the SQL side.

Fortunately, there's another way, which is to create the object from simple types on the Azure Cognitive Search side using a shaper skill.

First, from the SQL side, emit the URL data you need as a simple string:

```sql
(select top 1 '.....') as [url])
```

Adapt to your specific case so you have the url as a single string in the data that goes into the indexer.

Then, add a shaper skill to your skillset, like so:

```json
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ShaperSkill",
  "context": "/document",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "$type",
      "source": "=\"file\""
    },
    {
      "name": "url",
      "source": "/document/url"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "output",
      "targetName": "file_data"
    }
  ]
}
```

This takes the `url` and creates a `file_data` object of the right shape from it and a literal string for `$type`. You can then use that with the document extraction skill.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I gave it a try and received the following error while trying to create the shaper skill.  _One or more skills are invalid. Details: Input '$type' source is an invalid expression (file): paths must begin with '/'_

Comment: Yeah, I got the literal syntax wrong. I'll update the reply.

Comment: It should have been `"=\"file\""`, I forgot the `=`. I checked that works and updated the reply.

Comment: @SannyJacobsson, please let me know if that worked for you (and mark as answer if it did). Thanks!